# Problemas de sentencias SQL para buscar registros a través de una fecha

Tags: html, sql, array, phpmyadmin, get

yo estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar paginas web y diseño de bases de datos, y como tal tengo conocimientos básicos en SQL, el punto es que desarrolle una pagina web para guardar mis gastos que realizo (pagar facturas, comida, etc.), quise filtrar los datos a través de una fecha mediante a un buscador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me muestra los resultados, y como tal ya lo intente desde el gestor de base de datos (PHPmyadmind) y si me muestra los resultados. Pero en la pagina no me muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta el código

```
<?php 

require"PHP/conexion.php";

if (isset($_GET['buscar'])){

  session_start();

  $p=$_GET['p'];
  $m=$_GET['m'];
  $c=$_GET['c'];
  $pr=$_GET['pr'];
  $f=$_GET['f'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM registros WHERE nombre_producto='$p' or Marca='$m' or precio='$pr' or 
        cantidad='$c' or fecha='f'";

  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

}else{
  session_start();

  $sql="SELECT * FROM registros";

  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: Pon un `echo $sql;` en tu script y dinos qué consulta SQL se está produciendo. Sin ver eso, y sin saber de qué forma están tus datos en la tabla no podremos saber qué está pasando realmente.

Comment: En el ćodigo que has puesto no te muestra nada porque no le estas diciendo que te lo muestre, tan solo estas realizando una consulta, pero no estas devolviendo ninguna tabla ni ningun dato. Por otra parte, en la consulta en el campo fecha lo tienes mal puesto, pues no usas `$f`, sino `f` a secas. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] de paso para aprender como funciona este sitio. Pulsa [edit] para agregar información a la pregunta.